# How to connect to linkedin using ng2-cordova-oauth?

Tags: cordova, angular, oauth, ionic2, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use [ng2-cordova-oauth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng2-cordova-oauth) to login with linkedin using cordova. but I'm getting this error when trying to login:

> The redirect_uri does not match the registered value.

This is my linkedin provider object:

```
  private linkedinProvider: LinkedIn = new LinkedIn({
    clientId: "XXXX",
    appScope: ["r_fullprofile"],
  });
```

and this is how I used it:

```
this.cordovaOauth.logInVia(this.linkedinProvider).then(success => {
        console.log("RESULT: " + JSON.stringify(success));
    }, error => {
        console.log("ERROR: ", error);
    });
```

The problem is that the other parameters linkedin requires aren't available, the ones that are mentioned here in step2 : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

how am I going to add them and use it, the facebook example has only these params, and when I try to add any of the linkedin params I get a compilation error:

```
const provider = new Facebook({
    clientId: string,
    appScope?: string[],
    redirectUri?: string,
    responseType?: string,
    authType?: string
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linkedin provider should look like this:

```
  private linkedinProvider: LinkedIn = new LinkedIn({ 
      clientId: client_id,
      appScope: ["r_basicprofile","r_emailaddress"],
      redirectUri: redirectUri,
      responseType: responseType,
      state:  state
  });
```

with responseType is always equal to 'code' and redirectUri always equal 'http://localhost/callback'. and state is a string value that you generate randomly.
you'll find client_id and client_secret values in your linkedin app page.
the "logInVia" function will return a promise containing the authorization_code, when you get it you'll need to get the access token and with it you issue another request to get the data you want.

the whole requests are documented [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) in step 3 and step 4. 
P.S: in step 4 don't forget the "Bearer" before the access token in the Authorization header.